# Find "n" in a list full of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I'm looking to go through a list and find any element with a number.

This is what i got so far

```
list = ['Alvarez, S', 'Crawford, B', 'Fury, 8', 'Mayweather, F', 'Lopez, 44']

num = '8'

for s in home_pitchers:
    if num in s:
        print(s)

print(ex)
>>> Fury, 8
```

What I'm looking to do is to have num be 0 - 9. I thought about using '[^0-9]' but that  didn't work.

Ultimately I'm looking to print out this

```
print
>>> Fury, 8
>>> Lopez, 44
```

Just a heads up, I'm pretty new to coding so some concept might go over my head

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `isdigit` method with `any` function. The `isdigit` method *return `True` if the string is a digit string, `False` otherwise.*

```
>>> lst = ['Alvarez, S', 'Crawford, B', 'Fury, 8', 'Mayweather, F', 'Lopez, 44']
>>>
>>> for s in lst:
...     if any(char.isdigit() for char in s):
...             print(s)
...
Fury, 8
Lopez, 44
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `re` library:

```
import re

lst = ['Alvarez, S', 'Crawford, B', 'Fury, 8', 'Mayweather, F', 'Lopez, 44']

list(filter(lambda x:re.match(".*[0-9]+$",x), lst))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['Fury, 8', 'Lopez, 44']
```

The pattern matches any string ending with one or more numbers.